# In Swift, is there any native, easy way to enable multi-touch selection on a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, multi-touch, multi-select

I'm trying to get this functionality in a much more complicated app, but I went ahead and made a simple app that shows my issue as well. You can find the project here https://github.com/timfuqua/MultiTouchTable.

In the project, I've created a simple table view inside a table view controller (I left the table view controller with the default name `ViewController`). I've created a data source (array of strings) and initialized it to be "Item 0" through "Item 9". I'm overriding `ViewController`'s `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, as well as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` from the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol so I can track what's being called.

I also have `ViewController` set up as a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` implementing `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceiveTouch)` just to print out the location of any touches that are received, but always returns true. The tap gesture recognizer is linked to a function called `didTap` and that function will just print out "Received tap" when called. I've also set the `cancelsTouchesInView` to true for the recognizer so that it will let taps go through to the table.

I have the table view set up in the storyboard to be `Selection: Multiple Selection` as well as in the section for `View` I have `Interaction: Multiple Touch` checked. I don't know if I even need `Interaction: Multiple Touch` checked, but I'm doing it anyways.

When I run the app in the simulator (and I've also tested on an iPad), and I select Item 3, for instance, I see Item 3 turn gray and in my debug console I see this printed:

`Touch received at location 431.0,151.0
Received tap
Selected cell Item 3`

As expected. When I then go to do a 2 finger selection by holding down the option key, adjusting the 2 gray cursor dots to where I have it spaced one cell height apart from each other and then holding shift to hold them in that position and moving them over Item 5 and 6 and clicking I get this in the console:

`Touch received at location 501.0,242.0
Touch received at location 501.0,286.0
Selected cell Item 6`

Only one of the 2 cells gets selected. And there's my issue. The gesture recognizer caught 2 touch locations, and you can see they are about a cell height's position apart in the y direction, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only called once, for Item 6, so only Item 6 is selected. I'd like it to select both.

The native Apple Reminders app will do this. If you open Reminders and go to Tasks and make a list of a few items, there is a selection circle to the left of each entry. If you tap one, it selects it. If you tap more than one circle at the same time (like with 2 fingers), it selects both. That's what I want. But I just can't seem to figure out how to do this natively. I just wish that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` was called for each touch point. That would fix it. But it isn't.

Any ideas as to how I can make this work? Or even an answer of, "No, that's not how it works. You have to manually handle the touches." is fine for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`?

Comment: Yes. In ViewController.swift, inside `viewDidLoad`, line 20: `simpleTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`, where `simpleTableView` is the outlet for the table view defined in the storyboard.